How can I find the unitaries for the Bloch-Messiah decomposition?
I'm currently trying to understand the Bloch-Messiah decomposition in quantum optics, which basically states that every second-order nonlinear quantum optical circuit can be decomposed into a combination of interferometers+single mode squeezers+interferometers. As references, I'm mainly following this Braunstein's paper https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9904002 and the review https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.04596 . Now, I want to find the BM decomposition of the example given by Braunstein (eq.10/11 of the paper cited above), whose symplectic matrix can be written as $T =\begin{bmatrix} U & V\\ V^* & U^*\end{bmatrix}$ with $U=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ $V=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. My first attempt follows Braunstein, i.e. focusses on finding the SVD of V, and then extend it to the whole matrix T. For instance, $V = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, but the unitaries are clearly not related to $U$ in any way, and thus I cannot unitarily decompose the whole T with two block-diagonal matrices containing the unitaries of $V$. The second attempt relied on the Takagi-Autonne decomposition, as introduced in the second reference. Here the BM is performed through two matrices $W, X$, with $W$ the unitary that Takagi-Autonne-decompose $V$ (which turns out to be $W = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1+i & 1-i \\ 1-i & 1+i\end{pmatrix}$), and $X=W^{\dagger}Y$, with $Y$ the unitary coming from polar-decomposing $T$ (in my case I think that $Y$ is just the identity matrix, but of course I could be wrong). Even in this second scenario, I'm not able to properly decompose the $U$ blocks with block-diagonal unitaries. I think that my failure mainly comes from the lack of a precise "recipe" to cook the BM, as for every BM theorem that I find it always says that "there exist" matrices that can indeed perform the decomposition, but since I suppose the latter is not unique, they do not give the right formula to perform it. Then my question is simply: how can I find the right, block-diagonal unitaries, that Bloch-Messiah decompose my matrix?

are you sure your $U$ has the right form or is it just a typo on your part?

@ZeroTheHero you are completely right, I edited the typo!

You should start by writing the real symplectic matrix associated with transformation in Eq. 10 of Braunstein. Note that the equation given is Braunstein relates a transformation between creation and annihilation operators, you first need to write the corresponding operation for quadratures.

I have updated the answer going step by step. Hope it helps.

You can write the transformation of in the Eq. 10 from Braunstein as
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\b_1^\dagger \\ b_2^\dagger \end{pmatrix} = \mathcal{S}  \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\a_1^\dagger \\ a_2^\dagger \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -\tfrac12 & 0 & \tfrac12 \\
\tfrac12 & 1 & \tfrac12 & 0 \\ 
0 & \tfrac12 & 1 & -\tfrac12 \\
\tfrac12 & 0 & \tfrac12 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
From it you can find the associated real symplectic matrix to be
\begin{align}
S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 0& 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = R \mathcal{S} R^\dagger \text{ with } R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{1}_2 & \mathbb{1}_2 \\ -i \mathbb{1}_2 & i \mathbb{1}_2 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
You can then use the matrix $S$ (not $\mathcal{S}$!) to follow the steps given in Box 2 of the review paper you mention (which is now published at https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/full/10.1139/cjp-2024-0070).
You can easily find the Polar decomposition of $S$ to be
\begin{align}
S = 
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 
\end{pmatrix} \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \begin{pmatrix}
 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix} = P Y.
\end{align}
If you partition the positive matrix $P = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} A & B \\ B^T & C \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ then you find $B=0$ and $A = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}  2 & 1\\
 1 & 3 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$, $C = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\begin{smallmatrix}  3 & -1 \\
 -1 & 2 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$.
Similarly you find $Y = U \oplus U$ with $U = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & -1 \\
 1 & 2  \end{smallmatrix}\right)$.
Then you can calculate
\begin{align}
M = \frac{1}{2}\left( A-C + i (B +  B^T) \right) = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix}
 -\frac{1}{2 } & 1 \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2 } \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
The last matrix has Takagi decomposition $M = W \Lambda W^T$ with
\begin{align}
\Lambda &= \tfrac12 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}\\
W &= \begin{pmatrix}
 -\frac{i \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}} &\
 \sqrt{\frac{2}{5+\sqrt{5}}} \\
 \frac{i \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)}{\sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}}} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{10} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
With this you are done, as you can write
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S} &= \begin{pmatrix} H & K \\ K^* & H^* \end{pmatrix} \\
H &= W \sqrt{
\mathbb{1} + \Lambda^2} (W^\dagger U) \\
K &= W \Lambda (W^T U^*)
\end{align}
The matrices $W, U$ and $\Lambda$ are all above.
You can also just do
import numpy as np
from thewalrus.decompositions import blochmessiah
from thewalrus.quantum import is_symplectic
import numpy as np
id = np.identity(2)
R = np.sqrt(0.5) * np.block([[id, id],[-1j*id, 1j*id]])
# Below is \mathcal{S}
mS = np.array([[1,-0.5,0,0.5],[0.5,1,0.5,0],[0,0.5,1,-0.5],[0.5,0,0.5,1]])
# We now calculate S
S = np.round(R @ mS @ R.T.conj(),12)

assert is_symplectic(S)
u, l, v = blochmessiah(S)
assert np.allclose(u @ l @ v ,  S)
assert is_symplectic(u)
assert is_symplectic(l)
assert is_symplectic(v)
assert np.allclose(u @ u.T, np.identity(4))
assert np.allclose(v @ v.T, np.identity(4))


I still don't get why I should transform back the matrix to the real (quadrature) case, since eq. 56 keeps care of bringing everything in the $a, a^{\dagger}$ basis... But even if this is the right procedure, the $S$ you found has null $M$ matrix, which does not provide any tool for Takagi-Autonne-decompose it. The $N$ instead, is a Jordan block, which is possibly even worse...

The reason why you need to transform back to quadratures is that the algorithm developed in https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.04596 is written for symplectic matrices acting on the quadratures, not the ladder operators.

For the transformation in Braunstein's paper and using the notation of Eq. 31 of arxiv.org/abs/2403.04596  you have that M  = [[-sqrt(0.2), sqrt(0.8)],[sqrt(0.8), sqrt(0.2)]] which is certainly not zero.

I see, thanks a lot for covering the whole steps. Now it is clear that the procedure in the second paper works for quadratures. My last question would be then: is there a way to find the BM decomposition of a symplectic matrix in the $a, a^{\dagger}$ basis, without the need of transforming back to quadratures?

I think for this case you can, as the matrix connecting the input and the output for the ladder operators is purely real. Not sure for the more general case.
